# WPF - ObservableCollection<object> DP

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I intend to create a Pager Control to restrict a ObservableCollection (with all kinds of types) to a defined amount. Therefore, I created a UserControl with following DP:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemSource", typeof(ObservableCollection<object>), typeof(PagerControl),new PropertyMetadata(null, ItemSourceChanged));

private static void ItemSourceChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PageControl pageControl = (PageControl)sender;
    PageControlViewModel viewModel = ((PageControlViewModel)pageControl.DataContext;
    viewModel.SetItemSource(e.NewValue);
}

public ObservableCollection<object> ItemSource
{
    get => (cast..)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty);
    set => SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value);
}
```

My idea is, after the ItemSource has been changed, my viewModel receives the new Collection and is able to register following event

```
public void SetItemSource(ObservableCollection<object> itemSource)
{
    this.ItemSource = itemSource;
    this.ItemSource.CollectionChanged += doStuff;
}
```

doStuff does something like: ItemSource.Skip().Take() and binds it to an other ObservableCollection, whichever can be used by DataGrids.

So far so good, but I encounter following problem. **ItemSourceChanged** gets called always (as soon as I bind it) and the ItemSource DP has already an instance and NOT the defined default value **null**. It always has an instance. If I bind the PagerControl's ItemSource to an ObservableCollection with some values, the ItemSourceChanged has no Entries at all and in addition, is not the same object as the one I bound it to. Therefore, **CollectionChanged** is never called when the original ObservableCollection receives some new entries.

PagerControl usage in the XAML

```
<DataGrid ItemSource={Binding ElementName=Pager, Path=RestrictedItemSource} />
<Pager x:Name="Pager" ItemSource={Binding Collection} />
```

The XAML viewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<Class> Collection { get; set; } = new ...();

public ViewModel()
{
    Collection.Add(x);
    Collection.Add(y);
    Collection.Add(z);
}
```

Note: Code snippets are from the top of my head.

Comment: Usually implementation of paging does not involve anyway of altering original item source. It just a display mechanism. So I'd suggest you use your itemsource as you would for any other control and just implement paging display of values. Here is an example I found by quick google search http://www.powerobjects.com/2013/02/19/wpf-paging-control-wpf-applications/

Comment: Yes, thats also something I am thinking about. But that does not solve my problem :) Even with this approach I face the same issue.

Comment: Maybe I'm just reading it wrong, but it looks to me like you created a loop. Changing `ItemsSource` just ends up setting the `ItemsSource` property again.  May wrap the code in`SetItemSource` inside an `if` so it only does that if the specified `itemSource` instance is *different* than the current instance.

Comment: SetItemSource is in the ViewModel of the PagerControl. So not related to the ItemSource DP. I use the ViewModel for the background logic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After 3 days of searching and this StackOverflow post, I finally found the mistake. My PageControl had his own ViewModel (DataContext) and therefore, the binding in the MainWindow.xaml (or whichever Control included the PageControl) could not bind the ItemSource correctly, because the PageControl's DataContext was his own one.

It is working flawlessly with following change

```
<DataGrid ItemSource={Binding ElementName=Pager, Path=RestrictedItemSource} />
<Pager x:Name="Pager" ItemSource={Binding Path=DataContext.Collection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Find, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```